# Bicep constraining values in a param array

Tags: azure-bicep

I have the following bicep param definition -

```
@minLength(1)
@maxLength(2)
param locations array
```

I want an array of between 1 and 5, strings, but the strings can only be from a list of known values.

Known values -
"sheep", "cow", "dog", "cat", "bird", "snake", "rat", "mouse"

how do i constrain my array so that it can only contain between 1 and 5 of these known animals?

Answer (score 1):

does below works for you ？bicep parameters [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/parameters)

```
@allowed([
  'sheep'
  'cow'
  'dog'
  'cat'
  'bird'
  'snake'
  'rat'
  'mouse'
])
@minLength(1)
@maxLength(5)
param animal string
```

Comment: will this work if i pass in ['sheep', 'cat'] but say prevent me from passing in ['sheep', 'foo']??

Comment: sorry, my bad, I misunderstood your question. what you want: 'it is a permutation and combination from a set of data', I do not think bicep parameter has this feature. You may need to provide all permutations and combinations in @allowed(). This is impractical when there is a lot of set data(animal)